# Attempt to present <a> on <a> while a presentation is in progress

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, swift4

i know this has been asked before but i'm trying to figure out the issue with my project, as the title states (a) is trying to present on (a) i have checked all segue triggers to see if i accidentally set a segue to go to the same view controller that it is already on but this is not the case.

view controller 1 code

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

class NotificationViewController: UIViewController {

    let isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications = UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications

    let current = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    @IBAction func Notification(_ sender: Any) {

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: {didAllow, error in})

        var i = 0

        while i < 1{

        current.getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { (settings) in
            if settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
                // Notification permission has not been asked yet, go for it!
            }

            if settings.authorizationStatus == .denied {
                i = i + 1
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToLocation", sender: self)
                    // Notification permission was previously denied, go to settings & privacy to re-enable
                }

            }

            if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
                i = i + 1
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToLocation", sender: self)
                    // Notification permission was already granted
                }

            }
        })
        }

        }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        current.getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: { (settings) in
            if settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
                // Notification permission has not been asked yet, go for it!
            }

            if settings.authorizationStatus == .denied {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToLocation", sender: self)
                    // Notification permission was previously denied, go to settings & privacy to re-enable
                }

            }

            if settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToLocation", sender: self)
                    // Notification permission was already granted
                }

            }
        })

        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

view controller 2 code

```
    import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class LocationViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textview: UITextView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBAction func OnLocation(_ sender: Any) {

        locationManager.delegate = self as? CLLocationManagerDelegate

        var i = 0

        while i < 1{

            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
            case .notDetermined:
                // Request when-in-use authorization initially
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                break

            case .restricted, .denied:
                i = i + 1
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToLogin", sender: self)
                }
                // Disable location features
                //disableMyLocationBasedFeatures()
                break

            case .authorizedWhenInUse:
                i = i + 1
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToLogin", sender: self)
                }
                // Enable basic location features
                //enableMyWhenInUseFeatures()
                break

            case .authorizedAlways:
                // Enable any of your app's location features
               // enableMyAlwaysFeatures()
                break
            }
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager,
                             didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {   switch status {

        case .restricted, .denied:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToLogin", sender: self)
            break

        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToLogin", sender: self)
            break

        case .authorizedAlways:
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToLogin", sender: self)
            break

        case .notDetermined:
            break
            }
        }
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

error message

> 018-02-27 23:06:41.534749+1030 Request[27358:1351259] Warning: Attempt
>   to present  on
>    while a presentation
>   is in progress!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No no no no no. This is not the way. sorry about this plenty of no´s but ***completionHandler*** result parameter of the ***requestAuthorization*** method from UNUserNotification **may** be executed on a background thread.

tips for this function

```
@IBAction func Notification(_ sender: Any)
```

*should start with lowercase

*provide a name that the action it accomplish can be inferred by that name

*change the type of the sender (if you know it), that way you can explicitly call properties or methods on that object without cast.

continuing with the rest of the code inside the scope of the function. **requestAuthorization** have the only responsibility of that -  ask for a permission - and the response is **didAllow** or **error**. You never check this and continue launching another block that response is also another thread

bottom line:  your calling **requestAuthorization** and then **getNotificationSettings** inside a loop (why?), you have a lot of luck if this code execute 30% of the time.

So you should separate some of the code involving permissions, read some lines about GRASP principle, also read every chapter [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW1)

Comment: i appreciate your help this worked i feel so dumb now

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is pretty clear `while a presentation is in progress`. That mean that you try to present `LocationViewController` from another `LocationViewController`, but it still not presented yet.

Move your presentation logic to `viewWillAppear` method. It will help

**UPDATE**

1) remove your existing segue from Notification button to `LocationViewController` in storyboard

2) Add segue from `NotificationViewController` to `LocationViewController` like it shown on picture
[image]

3) Set name for this segue
[image]

Now try to run your project

Comment: there is only one LocationViewController in my app thats why i am confused

Comment: and what are you doing with this method call `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToLogin", sender: self)` inside your `LocationViewController `? Didn't you tried to present another `LocationViewController `?

Comment: there is a third view controller i have named LogInViewController but i did not add this code because as of yet it is a blank view controller with nothing but a segue to it from Location if a condition is met

Comment: try to comment this presentation(for all conditions) and see if you will still has this issue

Comment: could you explain a little more i'm fairly new to swift and teaching myself because theres no one hear to teach me

Comment: @BenMarkSilkstone your segue from `NotificationViewController` is connected to `Notification` button?

Comment: yes so the button asks the user to allow notifications and it also sets a while loop going to check if the user has allowed or denied notifications, once it determines it, it then performs the segue to LocationViewController

Comment: Nope. If your segue is connected to the button, then it's open `LocationViewController` each time when you press Notification button. So, in your case, you open `LocationViewController` twice - once from code and once from Storyboard. Connect you segue to controller, instead of button

Comment: how would you recommend doing this please provide code etc